# Where do the factors $\eta_i$ come from?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

My question refers to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.08288.pdf), p. 5, Lemma 2.

It is said that each local equilibrium is of the form $\rho(x,t)F(v)$ with $F_i(v)=\eta_i M_i(v), i=1,\ldots,N$. As far as I see, $\rho(x,t)=\sum_{i=1}^N \rho_i(x,t)$ as is defined on page 4. Thus, writing out the components, this seems to mean that each local equilibrium is of the form
$$
(\rho(x,t)\eta_1 M_1(v),\ldots,\rho(x,t)\eta_N M_N(v)).\tag{1}
$$

On the other hand, in the proof of Lemma 2, it is shown that for a local equilibrium one has $f_i(x,v,t)=\rho_i(x,t)M_i(v)$ for $i=1,\ldots,N_l$. And for $i=N_l+1,\ldots,N$, it holds $f_i(x,v,t)=\rho_i(x,t)M_i(v)$ anyway, cf. page 4 after (6). So due to this, a local equilibrium shall be of the form
$$
(\rho_1(x,t)M_1(v),\ldots,\rho_N(x,t)M_N(v)).\tag{2}
$$

I do not see how (1) and (2) do fit together, i.e. where the extra factors $\eta_i$ arise from.

**EDIT:**

I think, what is meant is the following.

$f_i(x,v,t)=\rho_i(x,t)M_i(v),\qquad i=1,\ldots,N$

and this implies that $(\rho_1(x,t),\ldots,\rho_N(x,t))$ solves
$$
\sum_{j=1}^N (k_{ij}\rho_j-k_{ji}\rho_i)=0,\qquad i=1,\ldots,N.
$$

Now, it is said that the solution space is spanned by $(\eta_1,\ldots,\eta_N)$, meaning that, for some constant $C$, we must have that
$$
(\rho_1(x,t),\ldots,\rho_N(x,t))=C(\eta_1,\ldots,\eta_N)
$$
and it remains to determine $C$. But,
$$
\rho(x,t)=\sum_{i=1}^N\rho_i(x,t)=\sum_{i=1}^N\int f_i(x,v,t)\, dv=\sum_{i=1}^N\int C\eta_i M_i(v)\, dv=C 
$$
since $\int M_i(v)\, dv=1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^N\eta_i=1$, that is, each local equilibrium is of the form

$(f_1(x,v,t),\ldots,f_N(x,v,t))=\rho(x,t)(F_1(v),\ldots,F_N(v))$ or, in shorter notation,
$$
\rho(x,t)F(v)
$$